# How to create a function in .bashrc that will work correctly when the command run by the function has spaces in it?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I have this function in ~/.bashrc for creating a permanent alias right from the terminal:

```
function permalias ()
{
  alias "$*";
  echo alias "$*" >> ~/.bashrc
}
```

The problem is it doesn't take into account that the command I'm creating alias for may have spaces in it, so something like `permalias ll='ls -l'` won't work correctly the next time I open up terminal.

How to make it work?

Comment: Uh. How is permalias better or different from typing just plain alias? permalias foo=bar  is the same as alias foo=bar, as far as I can see.

Comment: @jimmcnamara: notice that he's appending the alias to his .bashrc file. So the difference is, 'alias foo=bar' is transient, 'permalias foo=bar' is saved for future sessions.

Comment: Yup.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the quotes to the ~/.bashrc:

```
 echo alias "'$*'" >> ~/.bashrc
```